# Обработка нажатий на СЕЛФИ-КНОПКЕ

Tags: java, android

Имеется селфи-кнопка ( допустим как на фото):

[image: описание изображения]

Каким образом обрабатывается нажатие на кнопку? Мне хотелось бы узнать, могу ли я перехватить нажатие  использовать его для своих целей, а не для снимка?

Comment: для каких например?

Comment: @Grundy , хочу чтобы выполнялись некоторые действия в моем приложении. Да хоть просто счетчик нажатий. Это, мне кажется, не имеет значения.

Answer (score 2):

Обычно "селфи палка" (Монопод) выступает в роли Bluetooth-клавиатуры. Кнопка "сделать фото" - на самом деле - кнопка *повышения громкости*.
По крайней мере, так работали все моноподы, которые я держал в руках.

Comment: Когда подключал устройство, которое на картинке к телефону на Андроиде, кнопка IOS - прибавляла громкость, а вот кнопка ANDROID - делала снимок. Поэтому думаю, что не совсем так\

Comment: @NikotinN, а вы попробуйте нажать на кнопку, не запуская приложение камеры. Или попробуйте нажать на кнопку увеличения громкости в режиме фронтальной камеры (на самом телефоне). По стандарту, нажатие на кнопку громкости в режиме фронталки делает снимок, даже без монопода. Поэтому большинство моноподов делают именно так

Comment: не запуская камеры при нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходит.

Comment: @NikotinN, на моем моноподе увеличивается громкость. В любом случае, вы можете например написать простое приложение, в котором перехватите onKeyPress, и посмотрите, что именно делает ваш монопод.